# GTK warnings during Geany running

Tags: 18.04, gtk3, geany

It's a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04. The Geany editor was installed by `apt`, but I'm getting a lot of console messages like below during running it:

```
(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.265: Error loading theme icon 'document-new' for stock: Icon 'document-new' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.422: Error loading theme icon 'document-open' for stock: Icon 'document-open' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.424: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Icon 'document-save' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.424: Error loading theme icon 'document-revert' for stock: 

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.425: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: Icon 'window-close' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.425: Error loading theme icon 'go-previous' for stock: 

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.425: Error loading theme icon 'go-next' for stock: 

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.427: Error loading theme icon 'system-run' for stock: Icon 'system-run' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.428: Error loading theme icon 'edit-clear' for stock: 

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.429: Error loading theme icon 'edit-clear' for stock: 

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.429: Error loading theme icon 'application-exit' for stock: Icon 'application-exit' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:22.435: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: Icon 'window-close' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker

(geany:4024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:48:25.021: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: Icon 'window-close' not present in theme elementary-xfce-darker
```

How to fix that?

Comment: If you use Elementary - it is off-topic here. If not - try to switch your theme `elementary-xfce-darker` to standard one (such as Radiance or Ambiance). Also you can try to contact your theme developer and ask them about missing icons.

Comment: @NOrbert - I know nothing about themes and icons. Are they part of GTK? It looks like my installation of Ubuntu misses something, needed for Geany

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem on 20.04 (WSL). Solved by installing `yaru-theme-icon`:

`sudo apt install yaru-theme-icon`

The `geany` package should depend on `yaru-theme-icon`, but it doesn't. It's a package management bug.

Comment: I have the same problem as in the question but I can't find a package `yaru-theme-icon` in Ubuntu 18.04. This answer is accepted as solution but I don't see how to solve this in 18.04. Do I need to include additional repositories?

Comment: @anol I just had the same issue here on Ubuntu 20.04, and the command in the answer resolved the problem. Are you sure your install went fine and you are getting the same messages?

Comment: this is the correct fix for ubuntu `22.04` too in `WSL2`

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on a headless 18.04 setup but the theme not being found was menta.
Installing the package `mate-themes` solve the issue in my case so I guess the proper solution for the case in the question would be also to install the missing theme. The package `xubuntu-icon-theme` seems the best candidate to me as it provides files in `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker/*`.

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, headless server. In my case, I was still receiving warnings that the Yaru theme was missing. The following package fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```